# Javascript нужно вставить в абзац символ

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, у меня такая ситуация.
Я имею текст:

```
<p>Loremasdadasdasd</p>
<p>Loremasdasdasd</p>
<p>loremadasdasdasd</p>
<p>asdasdasdasdasda</p>
```

Мне нужно, на каждый четный абзац вставлять символ `{{id}}`

Я это сделал так:

```
 var ids = [];

 var selRel = function(id) {

     ids.push(id);

     let newStr = jQuery('#ed_ru')
         .val()
         .split("<p>")
         .filter(el => !el.match(/\{\{(\d{1,8})\}\}/))
         .map((el,it) => {
            return (it == 2) ? '{{'+id+'}}' + el : el
         })
         .join('<p>');

         jQuery('#ed_ru').val(newStr);

         let newStrMd = jQuery('#ed_md')
                        .val()
                        .split("<p>")
                        .filter(el => !el.match(/\{\{(\d{1,8})\}\}/))
                        .map((el,it) => {
                           return (it % 2 == 0) ? '{{'+ids[it]+'}}' + el : el
                        })
                        .join('<p>');

                        jQuery('#ed_md').val(newStrMd);
   };
```

Но у меня есть проблемы, во-первых, он не вставляет на четные абзацы символ `{{id}}`.
Во-вторых обрезается текст. Как поправить?
Сами абзацы берутся из input type hidden.

- Также символы типа `{{}}` не вставляются иногда в параграфы.

**UPDATE**

У меня есть массив:

```
var ids = ['212341', '2313213', '323134', '213132'];
```

Мне нужно, чтобы на каждый четный абзац шло уникальное значение из этого массива, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так, если я правильно понял.

```js
var add = function(id) {
  $('p').each(function(i) {  // Для каждого параграфа
    if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)    // Если индекс кратный 2... 
      $(this).append('{{' + id + '}}'); // То добавляем текст
  });
};

add('id');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
```

Comment: Это работать не будет, у меня код html идет в input, То есть абзацы берутся из value, я ж не зря `val()` использую))

Comment: @Kexer такие подробности надо в вопросе указывать)

Comment: Проблема в том, что не работает правильно оно. Тут map используется вообще.

Comment: из текстарии какой  нить

Comment: Я обновил вопрос..

Answer (score 0):

превратите ваш кусок html-строки в jquery объект и работайте с ним как обычно.

```js
var ids = ['99999', '2313213', '323134', '213132'];

var data = $("#x").val();
var m = null;

var regex =  /{{(\d{1,8})}}/g;
while( m = regex.exec(data) ){  
   var idx = ids.indexOf(m[1]);
   if(idx >= 0){
       ids.splice(idx, 1);
   }
}


var $data = $(data).wrapAll("<div></div>").parent();

  $data.find("p")
       .filter(function(i,v){
          return (i % 2 == 0) && !(regex.test($(v).text()));
       })
       .slice(0, ids.length)
       .each(function(i,v){          
           $(v).prepend('{{' + ids[i] + '}}'); 
        });   
  
  console.log($data.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="x" type="hidden" value="<p>Loremasdadasdasd1</p>
<p>Loremasdasdasd2</p>
<p>{{99999}}loremadasdasdasd3</p>
<p>asdasdasdasdasda4</p>
<p>loremadasdasdasd5</p>
<p>asdasdasdasdasda6</p>
"/>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75205/discussion-on-answer-by-teran-javascript-----).

Comment: @Kexer, отписался в чатике